# Combination table of elements from another table

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table of arguments which looks like this:

| argument 1 | argument 2 | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| elem1 elem2 | elemA | 8 | 15 |
| elem1 elem2 elem3 | elemB elemC elemD elemE | 16 | 32 |
| elem1 elem2 elem3 | elemF elemG elemH elemI | 39 | 42 |
| elem4 | elemF elemG elemH elemI | 42 | 83 |

Elements in first and second column are strings, for example:

elem1 = 'Rio de Janeiro', elem2 = 'Tokio', elemA='New York' and so on...

Min and max columns are ranges and can be both treated as argument 3.

I am trying to write down a table of every possible combination of elements from argument 1 column with arguments 2 and 3, like this:

| argument 1 | argument 2 | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| elem1 | elemA | 8 | 15 |
| elem2 | elemA | 8 | 15 |
| elem1 | elemB | 16 | 32 |
| elem1 | elemC | 16 | 32 |
| elem1 | elemD | 16 | 32 |
| elem1 | elemE | 16 | 32 |
| elem2 | elemB | 16 | 32 |
| elem2 | elemC | 16 | 32 |
| elem2 | elemD | 16 | 32 |
| elem2 | elemE | 16 | 32 |
| elem3 | elemB | 16 | 32 |
| elem3 | elemC | 16 | 32 |
| elem3 | elemD | 16 | 32 |
| elem3 | elemE | 16 | 32 |
| elem1 | elemF | 39 | 42 |
| elem1 | elemG | 39 | 42 |
| elem1 | elemH | 39 | 42 |
| elem1 | elemI | 39 | 42 |
| elem2 | elemF | 39 | 42 |
| elem2 | elemG | 39 | 42 |
| elem2 | elemH | 39 | 42 |
| elem2 | elemI | 39 | 42 |
| elem3 | elemF | 39 | 42 |
| elem3 | elemG | 39 | 42 |
| elem3 | elemH | 39 | 42 |
| elem3 | elemI | 39 | 42 |
| elem4 | elemF | 42 | 83 |
| elem4 | elemG | 42 | 83 |
| elem4 | elemH | 42 | 83 |
| elem4 | elemI | 42 | 83 |

I have no idea what formulas should I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to reddit user [u/MattyPKing](https://www.reddit.com/user/MattyPKing/) I found a solution.

For anyone interested here is [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AQWWPAeftN_9Htihx9xsvhl3usSKJ6o0k_TAK0HCdE8/edit?usp=sharing) he sent me.

Answer (score 0):

In the example data, `elem1 elem2` uses a space as separator, but `Rio de Janeiro` also includes spaces. It is unclear whether the data is in a format that can be parsed programatically.

In the event the real data does not include strings like `Rio de Janeiro`, or you are using separators other than spaces, try something like this to get started:

`=arrayformula( split( query( flatten( split(A1:A10, " ") & "|" & B1:B10 & "|" & C1:C10 ), "where not Col1 starts with '|' ", 0 ), "|" ) )`

Replace the `" "` with the separator character you are using.

The formula will expand column A but not column B. To expand column B as well, apply a similar formula to the results from the first one.

Comment: In fact, I described those as elements because the strings for these elements contain spaces. I guess I can replace it with something else to distinguish them from spaces between elements.

Comment: Please share a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if what I did will work for you, but it seemed to have worked with the test data that you have uploaded. It is not one formula, but rather a few that automatically update the "Final Result" when you change the test data.

Here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NsKLaxUw-fvD4ezfu4cBn_tAN4MIQU1qHGWWB6q631o/edit?usp=sharing) to the spreadsheet.

The formula in the first column under final result would be enough to get all of the combinations, but there is a hard cap of 50,000 characters on the `CONCAT` formula, which I do not know how to bypass.

**EDIT:**

I have changed the calculator to match what you were trying to achieve:
[image]

You will find the new version on the "EDIT" tab.

If you are using data that is different from the "Test Data" that is referenced in the formulas, just make sure to change around the references in the formulas to fit your new data. I have also added these instructions in the [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NsKLaxUw-fvD4ezfu4cBn_tAN4MIQU1qHGWWB6q631o/edit#gid=1769929545).

Comment: Not really the result I wanted to achieve but it's close. In fact I wanted every element from argument 1 to correspond to argument 2 for only it's row. This means elementA should only correlate with element1 and element2, and so on.

Comment: I have changed the calculator according to this. Please see my edited answer. If your question has been resolved, please mark this thread as answered.